# Finding all solutions to subset sum for integers with bounded weights

Tags: dynamic-programming, np-hard

Suppose I have the set of weights $W = \{w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_{50}\}$ where each $1 \le w_i \le 60$ is an integer.  I am interested in determining **all** subsets (not just one, and not just the number of them) of $W$ with a fixed sum $s$.  I realize this is obviously NP-hard, but are there some efficient ways (e.g. dynamic programming) to obtain this result for these relatively nice conditions (e.g. only 50 items, weights integer and bounded)?

Answer (score 4):

The dynamic programming algorithm can be adapted to give all solutions. You create a table $A$. The cell $A_{k,w}$ contains enough information to enumerate all subsets of $\{w_1,\ldots,w_k\}$ summing to $w$. When $k = 0$, this is trivial. Given $A_{k-1,\cdot}$, $A_{k,w}$ points at the two cells $A_{k-1,w},A_{k-1,w-w_k}$ (if they exist). The second pointer is also annotated with $w_k$. If you look at $A_{50,W}$, you can reconstruct all subsets by considering all paths going all the way to $A_{0,0}$. This can be done using a simple recursive procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. 
Have a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution

Comment: However, this seems to only give the existence of such a subset -- whereas, I am interested in determining **all** such subsets. Do you have an idea of how I could modify it to obtain that?

Comment: You will create an array (2-D). There you can find what you are looking for ("stepping back"). There is a rich material of this problem on the internet. Just google subset sum dynamic programming.

Answer (score 0):

I created a Python module called "[subsetsum](https://pypi.org/project/subsetsum/)" that does exactly this. Hope it helps.

Comment: Technically not an on-topic answer for this site but I think it's useful, so I'll count it as an exception. Welcome to CS.SE!

Answer (score -1):

Look at the coin change problem.  Solutions are known which will give all results.  If you have a problem with it, I can provide some code.

See http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Coin_Change for example

Comment: The coin change problem that you refer to, especially the 3 variants mentioned in the link you provide, all can use the same coin multiple times. This is not the case in the question. The question is the subset sum problem, even if this too can be solved using dynamic programming.

Comment: That's not the problem same.